# Create React App Rewired application ignoring jest.config.js

Tags: configuration, config, create-react-app, ts-jest

I have a react application created using "create react app rewired". I've installed ts-jest and want to be able to customize Jest. I read the documentation from ts-jest and executed `npx ts-jest config:init` at the root level of my project to create the initial configuration file. To test that jest is indeed using that configuration file, I wrote the following line `console.log(window);` in a sample test file and modified the configuration such that `testEnvironment` is set to "node".

I am expecting the test to fail due to `window` being undefined, but I am getting the window object back. I tried renaming the file to `jest.config.ts` and I got the same result.

I did a global search across all the files to see if there's another configuration file somewhere that is overriding my configurations, but there was none found.

What am I doing wrong? I know jest comes pre-packaged with create-react-app (CRA). I would imagine that create-react-app-rewired would only include some wrapper above CRA so where is it getting its configurations from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've come to realize that create-react-app-rewired package had nothing to do with this issue since it is simply a wrapper package that exposes a `configure-overrides.js` file to allow developers to modify the webpack configurations managed by create-react-app.

The `jest.config.ts` or `jest.config.js` config file I created had no effect because [create react app (CRA) will generate and use its own jest config file](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/scripts/utils/createJestConfig.js) underneath the hood.

I discovered this by happenstance while researching on another issue. A [comment by dstapleton92](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9131#issuecomment-668790615) on GitHub helped me draw this conclusion.

[Create React App supports overriding SOME of the values](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/scripts/utils/createJestConfig.js#L74) via the "jest" property in `package.json` file. Upon inspecting the [jest config factory function in CRA](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/scripts/utils/createJestConfig.js), `testEnvironment` property is hard coded to "jsdom" and the key is not exposed as part of the list of overridable properties.

This is why the attempts I made were not successful.

Comment: Curiously, the `transformIgnorePatterns` isn't functioning correctly for me, even though the source code (and my local version) says it should work otherwise.

Comment: Turns out it was because of `react-app-rewired`, which takes over the handling of the `jest` section of `package.json`. And, unlike CRA, it performs a [concatenation instead of replacement](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/blob/bfe2390b92bb2f32864bdd09b1b6bbecdc261960/scripts/utils/rewireJestConfig.js#L22). So it was retaining the original ignore pattern for `transformIgnorePatterns` rather than overwriting like CRA would